# How to create a linked list by adding nodes at the end?

Tags: c, linked-list

I wrote a program where the user is asked whether he wants to insert a new node in the linked list (insertion at end) and then print the whole linked list. Anytime the user enters the value 0, the program stops and prints the linked list upto that point.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct ListNode
{
   int  data;
   struct   ListNode    *next;
};

int main()
{
    int     val,
            flag = 1;

struct  ListNode    *p,
                    *head,
                    *temp;
                    
printf("press 0 to exit\n");

do
{
    printf("enter the data : ");
    scanf("%d", &val);
    
    p = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
    
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        p -> data = val;
        p -> next = NULL;
        head = p;
        temp = p;
    }
    else
    {
        p -> data = val;
        p -> next = NULL;
        temp -> next = p;
    }
    
    printf("continue?");
    scanf("%d", &flag);

 }while(flag != 0);

 temp = head;

 while(temp != NULL)
 {
    printf("%d -> ", temp -> data);
    temp = temp -> next;
 }
 printf("\n");

 return 0;
 }
```

Now the problem I am getting with the output is that it is only printing the first and the last node. Other nodes in between are not being printed.

Here is a sample output:

> Numbers: 12 13 14 15
>
> Output: 12 15

Could anyone please explain to me where I am going wrong? I could always put the whole thing in a function and do it, but for now I wanted to try the same without using a function call.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest that you use a debugger or add `printf()` calls in order to see the values of variables in your program. This will help you figure out what is happening in your code. Learning how to debug code is an important skill, probably more important than writing code in the first place.

Comment: 1) `head` is uninitialized. 2) `temp -> next = p;` --> `temp = temp -> next = p;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: You're one of the nice guys ... and of the ***fastest***! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following if-else block,

```
 if(head == NULL)
    {
        p -> data = val;
        p -> next = NULL;
        head = p;
        temp = p;
    }
    else
    {
        p -> data = val;
        p -> next = NULL;
        temp -> next = p;
    }
```

Initially, when head is `NULL`, you are assigning `head` and `temp` both to `p`. So, temp points to the first element. After that, each time you get a new element, you are reassigning `temp->next` to that new element, without updating `temp`. Effectively, you are assigning `head->next` each time. To correct this, you need to update `temp` each time,

```
if(head == NULL)
    {
        p -> data = val;
        p -> next = NULL;
        head = p;
        temp = p;
    }
    else
    {
        p -> data = val;
        p -> next = NULL;
        temp -> next = p;
        temp = p;

    }
```

While declaring `head`, you also need to initialize it to `NULL`, as initialization is not done by default for local variables in C.

Comment: Global variables ARE initialized by default (to 0) in C.  Only local variables are not initialized by default.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! It worked! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are following issues:

1. `head` is not initialized, as mentioned by BLUEPIXY in comments.

   ```
   struct  ListNode    *p,
                       /* *head, */ // ISSUE: head not initialized
                       head = NULL,  
                       *temp;
   ```
2. When adding additional node, you are not updating `temp`

   ```
    else
   {
       p->data = val;
       p->next = NULL;
       temp->next = p;
       temp = p;       // NEED to update temp
   }
   ```

Also, there is no need to cast the result of `malloc`.

Also it is recommended to check if `malloc` succeded or not by checking its return value. Like, in this case:

```
p = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
if (p == NULL) {
    /* malloc failed. Code to handle the error */
}
```

Comment: thanks for the update info on typecasting of malloc! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the current node i.e `p` in `temp` only when u created the very first node.

U need to modify this code snippet from

```
if(head == NULL)
    {
        p -> data = val;
        p -> next = NULL;
        head = p;
        temp = p;
    }
    else
    {
        p -> data = val;
        p -> next = NULL;
        temp -> next = p;
    }
```

to

```
if(head == NULL)
    {
        p -> data = val;
        p -> next = NULL;
        head = p;
        temp = p;
    }
    else
    {
        p -> data = val;
        p -> next = NULL;
        temp -> next = p;
       temp=p;
    }
```

Now it will work fine.You need to store the pointer to current node `p` in `temp` after each iteration of `while` loop.

Comment: thanks a lot for he detailed explanation